# What technologies do i need to learn to make a blog?

Tags: html, php, wordpress, css, javascript

I am making my first website which will be my personal blog. My main purpose to make this is to learn website development. I know a fair amount of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I understand these are all front side technologies. So do i need to learn php as well or that could be taken care by Wordpress? Should i make the website from scratch by writing every html tag myself or is there a better approach? I am really confused, since i am investing my time and money, i want to do this right. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest rewording the question to not ask for opinions if you can. StackExchange communities don't usually allow those types of posts.

Comment: I dont know how can i change it. I just need to know what else do i need to learn and what is the best approach?

Comment: Is your goal to ultimately get hired by another company to do this?

Comment: My goal is to learn from this, so i can do some freelance work.

Comment: Sorry but the question is too board, to opinionated and at the same time off topic as we do not allow recommendations on websites, services, resources and software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broad answer for a broad question.

Pick any single technology (language, framework, library, etc.) for any tier and you'll often find that it was developed to best solve one particular subset of problems and will be lacking in other areas. Nothing out there is perfect. Each company has different needs and if you want to expand your marketability as an employee as quickly as possible, you should just find the most popular ones and learn them first. If you're freelancing, you get to pick your own preferences. There is no "right" solution that handles everything nor is there an objectively correct order for learning this stuff. A blog (or any type/part of a website) could be created in sooo many different ways and new solutions are coming out all the time.

That said, Wordpress is a very popular solution. It may benefit you to learn how to implement and work with it. Just keep in mind that, while you will find that it works very well in some cases, other technologies may have it beat in other areas. In a lot of cases, what you choose (or your company chooses) is a matter of preference and/or up to applicability to the problem at hand.